# Java - getting error with audio input stream for opening mp3 file

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to convert mp3 to wav file and I need the below lines of code to be able to proceed with the conversion post opening the mp3 file, however I get error -

```
    AudioFileFormat inputFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new      File("C:/dg.mp3"));
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:/dg.mp3"));
```

Error:

javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(Unknown Source)
    at MP3toWav.main(MP3toWav.java:10)

Any help on this is appreciated? I have searched a lot but unable to get any answers for my problem!

Comment: `UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type` Could this be any more clear? AudioInputStream cannot read mp3 with regular JRE.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can read an mp3 file with regular JRE and not use any other Java API?

Answer (score 1):

With default Java API, you can open a .wav file. But cannot open an Mp3 file. Use [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR) for open a mp3 file.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can read an mp3 file with regular JRE and not use any other Java API or 3rd party frameworks?

Comment: Otherwise install mp3 plugin http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html. You can't open mp3 with regular JRE.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open mp3 file with the default Java Audio API. You will have to use external API like [Mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)

Comment: Is there any way in which I can read an mp3 file with regular JRE and not use any other Java API?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to write your own MP3 decoder. You should start reading the MP3 specification.

Answer (score 0):

With default Java API you can only open `.aiff`, `.au` or `.wav` files. You could try to convert your `.mp3` to a `.wav` file and then use your new `.wav` file.